# Wait until SQL Server Agent Job finishes

Tags: vb.net

I am running a query to execute/start a SQL Server Agent Job which takes sometimes 4 to 5 hours to finish.  I would like to wait until that job finishes and then continue with the program/code.

Here is my query I am running to start the stored procedure:

```
                Dim connectionString As String = "HIDDEN"
                Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

                con.Open()
                Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'FWP FULL Daily'"
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
                //  -- WAIT UNTIL STORED PROCEDURE FINISHES --

                //Continue Code From Here on..........
```

How would I do this??

Thank you.

Comment: don't "wait" for the job to end? put an extra step at the end of the job to trigger whatever the next step should be?

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Why are you calling a SQL Agent Job from VB? The whole purpose of the SQL Server Agent is to schedule jobs, which you can start from SQL Server.

Comment: So is there no way to do this?

Comment: Along with the others, I'm immensely curious what SQL Agent Job takes 4-5 hours, and why you're trying to fire it from within ADO (command timeouts aside). Do you know there's a SQLCMD command line utility, and that you could spawn that as a Process, which provides for WaitForExit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx